# Type casting a struct into int

Tags: c, type-conversion

Hello every one I want to ask a question about type casting.It confuses me two much.
I am writing a code in which I am using an already created function having prototype like this.

```
void function (uint8_t * output , const uint_8 * buffer , int bufferlen);
```

it is called like this

```
const char * text = "some text";
uint8_t result[16];
function (result, (uint8_t *)text , strlen(text));
```

But my problem is that I have to call the same and pass it a struct so I call the function like this

```
const struct mystruct * ms;

function (result, (uint8_t *)ms , sizeof(*ms));
```

But it giving me segmentation fault.
can any one guide me what should I pass in place of third argument.

Thanks

I ma using C programming linux

Comment: I think we need to know more about `function`.  What does it do and why do you need to pass it a struct pointer instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

How big is the Struct? Your result has a particular length, 16, I'm guessing that the function your are calling is copying into result. If it's too small you have a problem.

Comment: then if it's bigger than 16, you are bound to get memory faults. Your result array must be big enough to hold a copy of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You declared an uninitialized pointer that does not point at valid memory.  That is why the function crashes when it tries to use that pointer.  Use this instead:

```
struct mystruct *ms = (struct mystruct *) malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)); 
function (result, (uint8_t *)ms, sizeof(struct mystruct));  
free(ms);
```

Or:

```
struct mystruct ms; 
function (result, (uint8_t *)&ms, sizeof(ms));
```

Comment: no no actually it is  initialized  i just have not wrote it here

Comment: @mainajaved: how do you expect people to help you properly if you don't show everything you are actually doing?  Making people guess just wastes their time.